# How to count number of elements of a multidimensional array without using loop in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a an array like below:

```
$array = Array
        (
            '0' => Array
                (
                    'num1' => 123,
                    'num2' => 456,
                ),
            '1' => Array
                (
                    'num3' => 789,
                    'num4' => 147,
                ),
            '2' => Array
                (
                    'num5' => 258,
                    'num6' => 369,
                    'num7' => 987,
                ),
        );
```

I want to count number of elements i.e. from `num1` to `num7` means I want output `7`. How can i do this without using loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `array_sum` and `array_map` function together.

try below solution:

```
$array = Array
(
    '0' => Array
    (
        'num1' => 123,
        'num2' => 456,
    ),
    '1' => Array
    (
        'num3' => 789,
        'num4' => 147,
    ),
    '2' => Array
    (
        'num5' => 258,
        'num6' => 369,
        'num7' => 987,
    ),
);

echo $total = array_sum(array_map("count", $array));
```

**output**

```
7
```

alternat way can be:

```
echo count($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE) - count($array); //output: 7
```

Comment: Really Nice and helpful Answer. You are faster than me.

Comment: I was going to say use `array_walk_recursive` , but second solution is perfect.

Comment: yes but in second answer if array have any associative key(not array eg `'3' => 10`) then the output will be wrong that is why i mentioned it as alternate way, but `array_map` will work perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Using array_sum function

```
$totalarray = array_sum(array_map("count", $array));
```

Using Foreach Loop

```
$count = 0;
foreach( $array as $arrayVal){
    $count += count($arrayVal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the standpoint of time complexity, a good functional iterator to only loop over the data once and directly return the total count is `array_reduce()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rlNn8))

```
echo array_reduce($array, fn($total, $row) => $total + count($row));
// 7
```